# Nginx proxy_pass to Tomcat non-root webapp?

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I would like to use nginx as a proxy to a Tomcat non-root app but am having problems to do that. This is the code that I use:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/app_v1.1.0/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
```

Now, this works ok for the app login screen but doesn't work for anything beyond that. After I login, the login page comes back so I think something is wrong with this kind of proxying, some kind of rewrite is obviously missing.

If I change it to something like:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

or:

```
location /app_v1.1.0 {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/app_v1.1.0
}
```

Then it works but i have to access my app via 'http:///app_v1.1.0' ... Can this be circumvented somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps this will answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936753/nginx-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat

Comment: I've tried it already, but that rewrite doesn't seem to help :-/ Maybe the application is broken in some way. I made a temporary fix by renaming app.war to ROOT.war and proxying '/' although I would like to do it the other way.